# Check folder exist using ftp library in codeigniter codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, ftp, directory

How to check the existence of a folder in a remote directory using ftp library in codeigniter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the list command

```
$this->ftp->list_files();
```

Then check if the directory you're asking for exists in the array

Comment: now getting full path of the folder,how to get the folder name?

Comment: different server return different format,some return its directory name and others return full path

Comment: in that case, use php's `strstr()` function ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php ) to check if it contains a slash, if it does, then use php's `explode()` function ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) where the string contains slashes to get the directory name. .